# Radius of convergence of: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {x^{n!}}{n!}$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

What the Radius of convergence of: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac {x^{n!}}{n!}$?

So far I tried finding the $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{(n+1)!}(n!)}{x^{n!}(n+1!)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{n!n}}{n+1}$

So I get two options:

1. $|x|\le1$ and the sum converges.
2. $|x|>1$ and the sum diverges.

So my radius is 1 or do I need to do: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}=$R for the option where my sum converges?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you did looks good to me. The direct formula for the radius of convergence is not applicable here, since most terms of the series (if rewritten in the form $\sum a_nx^n$) vanish.

Comment: @vadim123, for $x = 1$ it gives the series for $e$.

Comment: @TheAlchemist : your work looks correct.  One nitpick: when you do the Ratio Test, you use the absolute values of the terms in the series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That we have convergence for $|x|\le 1$ follows  by comparison with the familiar $\sum\frac{1}{n!}$.

For $|x|\gt 1$, we have divergence, because in fact the terms blow up: $\frac{x^N}{N}$ certainly does not approach $0$ as $N\to\infty$. Take $N=n!$.

So the radius of convergence is $1$.

**Remark:** Convergence tests are useful, and indeed we used two simple ones. But in thinking about whether a series converges or diverges, it is best to start with the series itself, and not with a test.

Comment: Actually my question is about the radius of converge, Is R=1 - (-1,1) is the radius of convergence?

Comment: I have added remark about radius of convergence. But it was not necessary. If we have convergence for $|x|\lt a$ and divergence for $|x|\gt a$, the radius of convergence is $a$.

Comment: Aight, Thanks. Exactly what i wanted to make sure.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Your remark is a very useful.